# Dense Domain: Preimage

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Given Banach spaces $X$ and $Y$.

Regard a bounded operator:
$$A\in\mathcal{B}(X,Y)\implies A\in\mathcal{C}(X,Y)$$

Then for dense sets:
$$W\leq Y:\quad \overline{W}=Y\implies\overline{A^{-1}W}=X$$

How can I see this?

Comment: Is $A$ linear ?

Comment: and do you mean $W\subset Y$

Comment: @Svetoslav: Yes, $A$ shall be a linear operator, and no, $W$ shall be a linear subspace.

Comment: Do you have some more information on $A$, like injective, onto or something ?

Comment: @Svetoslav: No, unfortunately nothing else. :/

Comment: This isn't true as stated. $A$ could be the zero map.

Comment: @KevinCarlson: For the zero map this is trivially true as then $A^{-1}W=X$.

Comment: Oh, silly, I wasn't thinking of $W$ as a linear subspace.

Comment: But I still think if you take $Y=\ell^1,W$ the sequences with finite support, $X=\mathbb{R}, A(1)=(1/n^2 e_n)$ that you'll get a counterexample, for then $A^{-1}W=\{0\}$.

Comment: @KevinCarlson: Right that answers my question. Can you post this as answer with the *Hilbert* space $\ell^2$?

Comment: @KevinCarlson: Ah wait what if both spaces agree $E=F$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $Af = \int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt$ in $L^{2}[0,1]$. Then $A : L^{2}\rightarrow L^{2}$ is bounded. Let $W$ consist of all continuously differentiable $g \in L^{2}[0,1]$ for which $g(0)=g(1)=0$. $W$ is dense in $L^{2}[0,1]$ because $\{ \sin(n\pi x) \}_{n=1}^{\infty}\subset W$ is an orthogonal basis of $L^{2}[0,1]$. However, $A^{-1}W$ is not dense because $f \in A^{-1}W$ implies $(f,1)=0$.

Comment: Ah right. Thanks!! Even more that can happen to any nontrivial proper orthogonal projection.

Comment: @Freeze_S : But I'm out to prove my conjecture that differentiation / integration is an example of everything really nice and everything really bad that can happen. :)

Comment: Haha, yes, so true!! ^^